# How to deploy Asp.Net Core application to Linux host?

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core

I'm very excited with new Asp.Net Core tend and trying to host it on cheap Linux host. But I'm still not succeed.

I have been developing my demo Asp.Net Core application using Visual Studio 2015 and now I want to deploy it to Linux host.

But I didn't find clear instruction how to do that. Here listed all ideas I found in different tutorials

1. Docker Linux Container. [this good article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-7.0) covering that.
2. Copy ASP.NET Core application to Linux Production Server  (or any other tools) and run it here ([link](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/publishing/linuxproduction.html)).
3. Is there any other easy way to supply Asp.Net Core application to Linux host?

Comment: @Illuminati: You always have to keep in mind that if a visitor comes in future and the link becomes obsolete, the answer is not good to him because the links don't work. That's why it's important to post the most relevant parts in the answer, so **future** readers can find the question useful too. SO is a Q/A page, not a forum/bulletin board for a personal questions/problem. I just gave you a hint and incentive to **improve** your question. If you quote the relevant parts or create an topic in the new StackOverflow documentation, the downvote will be removed and turned into an upvote

Comment: You have listed all the ways currently. Asking for an "easy way" is beyond SO's scope.

Comment: @LexLi, My question related on only searching "another" way. It's also about "how to suply running locally container with Asp.Net Core to production server".

Comment: @AdelNazirov: Do you with "supply" mean "deploy"? For deployment you have several options, one being using a private docker registry for hosting your Docker containers and pulling and starting them with the docker command line tools. Alternatively you run container cluster manager like Kubernetes, Rancher, Docker Swarm etc. But as Lex Li pointed out, explaining how to setup Kubernetes or Ranger is beyond the scope of a single question

Comment: @Tseng, under supply I mean deploy to real production server new product release. All these tutorials are good for study purposes. But in fact we should supply releases and hotfixes often than "once per year" (in our product we deploy every 1-2 weeks), in other word CI. In my vision it should be something very easy, like "Publish" button in VS for App services. I understand that there is no such magic button, but I expect one-two commands to deploy new release to Linux host.

Comment: @Adel It will better to run it on Windows Server environment. Never try to host it on Linux platform. If you can make it run, you can share the steps. :)